# iFrames lose focus of my parent page and can't function

Tags: html, iframe

I'm working on Oracle WebCenter portal extension in JDeveloper 11.1.1.7 and I recently added a page link (html page) from the content repository, that redirects inside an `iFrame` element, an external application I have on my DataCenter (not compatible for direct integration, hence the iFrames).

My problem is, when I click on the menu to get redirected on this page, everything works fine, but when I want to use the menu or any other elements outside the iFrame, it does not function, its like my whole application have 100% focus on `iFrame` page.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have your specified any z-index property?

Comment: no, i have never used z-index property

Comment: let me explain more my problem. I have a default template, that contains my menu, when i use iframe on a page that contains my template, the template could not function. As i understand z-index is for prioritizing the css objects. not getting out of the current focused object.